# How to configure an ASP.Net Core 2.0 API to use Azure AD as Identity Provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-app-service-envrmnt

OK, so I am creating a new project in VS2017 for an ASP.Net Core 2.0 API. I have and Azure AD set up and on the wizard to set up a new project, I select Change Authentication and schhose "Work or School accont" then enter the name of my Azure AD (i.e. mycompany.onmicrosoft.com). The project gets created and I can see the addition of this code in the Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAdBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

and I can see the settings added to the appSettings.json file

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mycompany.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
},
```

Where TenentID is the Directory ID for the Azure AD
 and ClientID is the ApplicationID value of the newly created API as it is now registered in the Azure AD.

This all makes sense.

But if I run the project in VS2017 and then navigate to the https://localhost:44348/api/values loc ation, I am getting a 401 Unauthorized.

That part I am missing that I must have to register my https://localhost:44348 browser instance somehow in Azure in order to identify it as the approved client application for my testing. But I am not clear where to do that. Do I just register https://localhost:44348 in the app registration for my Azure AD wor am I supposed to generate a key in the app registration for the Anew API project in Azure AD and pass that key as a secret in my auth header somehow?

What if I wanted to test this using Postman? How would I do that? Do I have to somehow register postman in Azure AD?

I have looked at many Google pages and there are plenty of examples showing how to do interactive login from web pages and then registering that web page sign-in url in Azure AD but not how to do it when simply trying to test an API from VS2017 debug or Postman.

How do I do that?

**EDIT - After reading the comments, I created a console application and I registered it in my Azure AD app registrations and created a key. I am providing it here for anyone else that may be trying to understand this process server to server OAUTH2 process.**

Credit to [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon) GitHub repo for help in the code design below;

Here is the console application code

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace API.TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// The AAD Instance is the instance of Azure.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Example: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}
        /// </remarks>
        private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];

        /// <summary>
        //  The Tenant is the Directory ID of the Azure AD tenant in which this application is registered.
        /// </summary>
        private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];

        /// <summary>
        /// The Client ID is used by this application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This value is obtained when this application is registered in Azure AD
        /// </remarks>
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];

        /// <summary>
        //  The App Key is a credential used by this application to authenticate to Azure AD.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This value is generated when this application is registered in Azure AD and assigned a key
        /// </remarks>
        private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppKey"];

        /// <summary>
        //  The Authority is the sign-in URL of the tenant.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This is a string combination of the aadInstance and the tenant
        /// </remarks>
        static string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

        /// <summary>
        /// The ApplicationID of the evsApi service in Azure
        /// </summary>
        private static string apiResourceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:ApiResourceId"];

        /// <summary>
        /// The base URL address of the Api service
        /// </summary>
        private static string apiBaseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["api:ApiBaseAddress"];


        private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        private static AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
        private static ClientCredential clientCredential = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // As a test, call the test Api, values endpoint 10 times with a short delay between calls
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            { 
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                GetValues().Wait();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async Task GetValues()
        {
            // Get an access token from Azure AD using client credentials.
            // If the attempt to get a token fails because the server is unavailable, retry twice after 3 seconds each.
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            int retryCount = 0;
            bool retry = false;

            do
            {
                retry = false;
                try
                {
                    // ADAL includes an in memory cache, so this call will only send a message to the server if the cached token is expired.
                    result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiResourceId, clientCredential);
                }
                catch (AdalException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.ErrorCode == "temporarily_unavailable")
                    {
                        retry = true;
                        retryCount++;
                        Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(
                        String.Format($"An error occurred while acquiring a token\nTime: " +
                        $"{DateTime.Now.ToString()}\nError: {ex.ToString()}\nRetry: {retry.ToString()}\n"));
                }

            } while ((retry == true) && (retryCount < 3));

            if (result == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Canceling attempt to contact the test API service.\n");
                return;
            }

            // Add the access token to the authorization header of the request.
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

            // Call the values endpoint in the test API service. This is an HTTP GET.
            Console.WriteLine("Retrieving values from Values endpoint at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiBaseAddress + "/api/values");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Read the response and output it to the console.
                string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Values Result:  {s}\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to retrieve Values\nError:  {0}\n", response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />

    <!-- This is the Directory ID value of the Azure AD -->
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" />

    <!-- This is the Application ID value of this test console application as it is 
       registered in the Azure AD app registration in the portal directory -->    
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" />

    <!-- This is the Key value of this test console application, as it is 
       generated in the keys section for "Test Console Key" in the Azure AD app registration 
       for this test console application in the portal directory -->
    <add key="ida:AppKey" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

    <!-- This is the Application ID value of the test api application as it is 
       registered in the Azure AD app registration in the portal directory -->
    <add key="api:apiResourceId" value="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" />

    <!-- This is the custom domain URL assigned to the test app service in the Azure   
        portal -->
    <add key="api:apiBaseAddress" value="https://testapi.mycompany.com" />
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Put simply, you need an access token. How do you get an access token? Through an authentication flow like Client Credentials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service. Or you might need to use OpenID Connect: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code. Client credentials will make the call as an app, while OIDC allows you to call the API as a user.

Comment: You will have to call as a user unless you add some permissions: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

Comment: Anyway, you will have to register the app that will call the API, and give it access to the API.

Comment: @juunas put this in as an answer so I can mark it as such. That was the part I was not connecting in my head. Once I looked at your comments and links, I created a console app and registered in in my Azure portal in the same AD as the API and then I used the appropriate values in the console app appSettings file and was able to talk to the API using the generated jwt bearer token.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that the quick comment helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply, you need an access token.

How do you get an access token? Through an authentication flow like OAuth Client Credentials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service.

Or you might need to use OpenID Connect: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code.

Client credentials will make the call as an app, while OIDC (and some other flows) allows you to call the API as a user.

You will have to call as a user unless you add some permissions: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

Anyway, you will have to register the app that will call the API, and give it access to the API.